# Update array geometry field using array lat & long field in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, array, update-query

I have two array columns in Postgres named *lat* and *long*. Both have 1-5 values in their array field. Like the following

[image]

Now I need to create geometry from each value based on the array index of *lat* & *long* field and update an array geometry column.
I have created the geometry from the fields by using the following query

**Query:**

```
select
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[1] :: double precision, lat[1] :: double precision), 4326),
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[2] :: double precision, lat[2] :: double precision), 4326),
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[3] :: double precision, lat[3] :: double precision), 4326),
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[4] :: double precision, lat[4] :: double precision), 4326),
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[5] :: double precision, lat[5] :: double precision), 4326)
from loc_table;
```

**Output:**

[image]

It creates separate columns but I need to update an array geometry column. I have tried using that select query first after so many failed attempts as following

**Query:**

```
select 
string_to_array(
concat(
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[1] :: double precision, lat[1] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[2] :: double precision, lat[2] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[3] :: double precision, lat[3] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[4] :: double precision, lat[4] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[5] :: double precision, lat[5] :: double precision), 4326)), ',' ) as geom 
from loc_table;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Then I tried with the update query with following

**Query:**

```
update loc_table
set geom_array  = string_to_array(
concat(
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[1] :: double precision, lat[1] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[2] :: double precision, lat[2] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[3] :: double precision, lat[3] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[4] :: double precision, lat[4] :: double precision), 4326), ',' ,
st_SetSrid(st_MakePoint(long[5] :: double precision, lat[5] :: double precision), 4326)), ',' );
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note that, the *geom_array* field/column is the array geometry type column and I know that the query made the geometry into the string. But that’s the best I can able to do.  And I have a large amount of data like 5-10 million. So, I have to use an efficient way to do so.
Can anyone please help me out with this?

I am using PostGIS 2.5 and Postgres 11.5.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL's `UNNEST` comes with a [multi-array table function signature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) that extracts given arrays into sets of rows with respect to their ordinality.

Inside an `UPDATE` statement this is rather straight forward to implement:

```
UPDATE loc_table
    SET geom_array = (
          SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x::FLOAT8, y::FLOAT8), 4326))
          FROM   UNNEST(long, lat) AS arr(x, y)
    )
;
```

---

**However:**

Keep in mind that the core paradigm of RDBS are *normalized relation*s, and the core feature for query performance is indexation, which, generally speaking, decreases in effectiveness with growing complexity.

In fact, you will not be able to index these geometries **while they are stored in arrays**, other than the actual **bounding box around all contained geometries**; run e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE loc_table
  ADD COLUMN geom_array_bbox GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 4326)  --needs to be generic GEOMETRY rather than POLYGON for single point arrays
;

CREATE INDEX ON loc_table USING GIST (geom_array_bbox);


UPDATE geom_array_test
    SET (geom_array_bbox, geom_array) = (
          SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(pt), 4326)::GEOMETRY,
                 ARRAY_AGG(pt)
          FROM   UNNEST(lon, lat) AS arr(lon, lat),
                 LATERAL ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326) AS pt  --save writing out the same point generation twice, for both SELECT columns
    )
;
```

to **store actual geometries** to work with, or, if storage space is at a premium (or there simply is no need to work with bbox *geometries*), simply index the array union:

```
CREATE INDEX ON loc_table USING GIST ( ST_Union(geom_array) );
```

Note here that any attempt to utilize the index needs you to explicitly call `ST_Union(geom_array)` in functions like `ST_Intersects`!

As a matter of fact, it may be a lot more convenient to **store the `geom_array` as a `MULTIPOINT`** in the first place:

```
ALTER TABLE loc_table
  ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(MULTIPOINT, 4326)
;

CREATE INDEX ON loc_table USING GIST (geom);


UPDATE loc_table
  SET geom = (
        SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Union(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x::FLOAT8, y::FLOAT8), 4326)))
        FROM   UNNEST(long, lat) AS arr(x, y)
    )
;
```

---

If you intent to being able to **filter for any of these grouped geometries *individually***, e.g. by spatial relation with another table, you may want to consider to **normalize** that multi value column into a related table, i.e. `UNNEST` the points into rows, with an id reference to the base table; an index may be more efficient, and the core RDB paradigms are honored.